# Launching Objects in Gazebo with ROS Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've been able to load objects in the past by using the following example code,

```
<!-- Blue Bar Cylinder -->
<model:physical name="cyl_model">
    <xyz>.6 0.4 1</xyz>
    <rpy>0 0 0</rpy>
    <static>true</static> 
    <body:cylinder name="cyl_body">
      <xyz>0 0 0</xyz>
      <rpy>0 90 90</rpy>
      <geom:cylinder name="cyl_geom">
        <xyz>0 0 0</xyz>
        <size>0 0</size>           
        <mass>1</mass>
        <visual>
          <size>0.03 0.03 .2</size>
          <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
          <mesh>unit_cylinder</mesh>
        </visual>
      </geom:cylinder>
    </body:cylinder>
  </model:physical>
```

Although now this doesn't work with ROS fuerte... I also tried the example in the Gazebo tutorials http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/SpawningObjectInSimulation

What am I missing here?  I'm not sure what has changed with loading objects into the gazebo simulator.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43114/launching-objects-in-gazebo-with-ros-fuerte/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-09-05**:
I just updated the gazebo setup instructions to install from released debians (http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo), please give that a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found a solution to this.  I was able to load the object if I spawned it in my world.launch file with the following code,

```
  <param name="sphere" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/objects/simple_sphere.xacro'" /> 
  <node name="sphere_model" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param sphere -model sphere1 -paused=true -x -.5 -y -.5 -z 1 " respawn="false" output="screen" />
```

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) with karma: 325 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1